# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Android build error

Tags: android, version-control, ant, tfs, ibm-mobilefirst

We have our project managed through Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) for source control.

When the Ant build script executes after doing a ‘Build All and Deploy’ on the Worklight project, I see this error:

> Buildfile:
>   C:\Users\ren04\Documents\Workspaces\MCAMWorkspace\MCAMWorklightPOCJQ\apps\Fourcast\android\native.externalToolBuilders\wlprebuild.xml
>
> run:
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Users\ren04\Documents\Workspaces\MCAMWorkspace\MCAMWorklightPOCJQ\apps\Fourcast\android\native.externalToolBuilders\wlprebuild.xml:10:
>   Can not change modification date of read-only file
>   C:\Users\ren04\Documents\Workspaces\MCAMWorkspace\MCAMWorklightPOCJQ\apps\Fourcast\android\native\res\xml\config.xml
>
> Total time: 342 milliseconds

These are the contents of the Worklight-generated wlprebuild.xml Ant script, which triggers the error:

```
<project name="wlprebuild" basedir="." default="run">
    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
                         5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
                         US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->

        <!-- This is worklight file that change timestamp of the AndroidManifest.xml when running as android project -->
        <target name="run">
                <touch file="../res/xml/config.xml" verbose="false"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

It is clear that when Ant tries to ‘touch’ the config.xml file in the TFS-managed Android worklight project, that it is unable to modify the timestamp. This is because the file is read-only and is managed by TFS to be read only, until it is modified in an editor (at which time it is checked-out from the source code repository and becomes editable).

My question is what purpose the ‘touch’ of the config.xml file serves, and whether the error it causes is something we need to address?

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

'Touch'ing the file is required, yes.

If memory serves me right, this was done due to the possibility of having web resources in the application not get updated after building the Worklight project in case of a time difference between the server and/or device between builds. Because of the timestamp, the web resources are now always up-to-date.

I did not try this myself, but perhaps you can either:

1. Keep the config.xml file write-able
2. Create a new file and point to it in wlprebuild.xml so that the 'touch' won't be in config.xml but to the other file